# Call class instance method while debugging in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

How do I call a class instance method while debugging in eclipse?

For example lets say I have the following code:

```
...
Canvas canvas = m_SurfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
canvas.drawColor(0xff000000);
...
```

And I have a breakpoint on the line canvas.drawColor. When I debug, the code stops at that line and I can view the variables inside canvas, but I also want to be able to call the methods inside canvas to see what they return like I can in visual studio, is this possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open the *Display* view, type the code you want to execute in it, select it, right-click, and click *"Execute"*, *"Display"* or *"Inspect"*, depending on what you want to do.