# reorganize list order during debug

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Call class instance method while debugging in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963252/call-class-instance-method-while-debugging-in-eclipse)

Is there a way to change order of list elements during debug?

how can I do it on Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [modify variables](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/shared/ref-changevarvalue.htm), ([see also](http://www.vasanth.in/2006/02/10/eclipse-tip-change-variable-values-while-debugging/)). Finally check out: [Call class instance method while debugging in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8963252). Once you can call arbitrary method during debugging, just call:

```
list.add(42, yourElement);
list.remove(7);
```

or whatever you want to do with that list.

PS: In [intellij](/questions/tagged/intellij) you can [run arbitrary expression during debugging](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/09/debugger-evaluate-expression-enhancements/) during breakpoint.

Answer (score 2):

**If your list is simple :**

While debugging in Eclipse, supposing you're in the Debug perspective, right click on your variable in the Variables view and choose "change value".

**If your list is complex :**

Simply add code somewhere in the execution path to modify the list. Be aware that the modified method execution may restart.

You may also add code in the condition text area of a breakpoint's properties.